# java force a methods parameter object type based on instance variable

Tags: java

Can i force a compile error based on a method instance variable? Consider the example classes below.

```
class MyObject{

    Class targetClass;

    public MyObject(Class<? extends Model> targetClass){
       this.targetClass = targetClass; 
    }

    public <T extends Model> void  doSomething(T model){
          //do some stuff
    }
}

class Customer extends Model {}

class Document extends Model {}
```

Could i instantiate `MyObject` with the `Customer.class` and then have it throw a compile error if i then call the `doSomething()` method with a `Document.class` instance?

```
MyObject object = new MyObject(Customer.class);

//this shouldn't compile
object.doSomething(new Document());

//this would be able to compile
object.doSomething(new Customer());
```

Edit*

I'm trying to come up with an ORM Relationship object. I'm instantiating the object with a base `Model` instance and a target class. For example, i'm creating a `HasMany` relationship object. I would instantiate the object with a `Customer` instance and a `Document` class. In my `HashMany` object i have a `.get()` method which returns all `Documents` attached to the `Customer` instance. I also have an `.attach(Model model)` method where i would feed it a `Document` instance and the method would attach the `Document` model to the `Customer` model in the database. I would like to force the `.attach(Model model)` method to only accept models from the class that the object was instantiated with. In this case, the `Document` class.

Comment: This smells like a case of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MattBall, I edited my OP with more info

Comment: Why not generics? `MyObject<Customer>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you should make the class - `MyObject`, itself generic as follows -

```
class MyObject<T extends Model>{

    Class<T> targetClass;

    public MyObject(Class<T> targetClass){
       this.targetClass = targetClass; 
    }

    public void doSomething(T model){
          //do some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: how could i make MyObject abstract? I'd like to make `doSomething(T model)` abstract but i can't figure out how to implement it in a subclass without getting compile error

Comment: Just add `abstract` keyword in front of the `class MyObject<T extends Model>` like - `abstract class MyObject<T extends Model>`. For the other part, it would be better if you would consider posting another question here.